# removing empty space of listview in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms.listview

I am using xamarin.forms listview for my project. The design is below:

```
<ContentView x:Name="Overlay" IsVisible="False"
                         VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="10,20,10,30"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                    <StackLayout Padding="20" BackgroundColor="#9C6114" Spacing="0">
                        <Label Text="Country Name" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <ListView x:Name="CountryList" HasUnevenRows="True" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsToggle}"></Switch>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding CountryName}"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.Footer>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button x:Name="btncancel" Text="Cancel" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#9C6114" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="btncancel_Clicked"></Button>
                                <Button x:Name="btnsubmit" Text="Submit" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#9C6114" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="btnsubmit_Clicked"></Button>
                            </StackLayout>            
                        </ListView.Footer>
                </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
```

For this listview, there is emplty space below the listview. I cannot remove the extra spaces in listview. Please see the attached image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88yOz.png)

Please help me to resolve this issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a problem that was similar to that. I followed this link: https://xamarinsharp.com/2017/05/20/xamarin-forms-listview-height-change-dynamically-using-mvvm-and-also-solve-empty-space-issue/

Basically, if you didn't already, you'll need to set up your project with MVVM. In your XAML you'll have to give a HeighRequest property to your listview and set it's value as: HeighRequest="{Binding Height}". In your viewmodel, add this:

int _height;

public int Height

```
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set
        {
            _height = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Height");
        }
    }
```

Then, in your viewModel's constructor (or wherever you set up your listview's objects), add this:

```
        Height = (**object**.Count * 60) + (**object**.Count * 10);
```

This worked just fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I found the following worked for me: I have a list view template with a Frame that contains a Grid. In my XAML file I added a SizeChanged event and BindingContext for the Grid:

```xml
...
<ListView x:Name="worksiteList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding WorksiteList}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SeparatorVisibility="None"
    HasUnevenRows="True">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                <Frame ...>
                    <Grid
                        SizeChanged="worksiteGrid_SizeChanged"
                        BindingContext="{Binding .}"
                        RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
                        ColumnDefinitions="50*,40*">
```

Then in code behind, I added the SizeChanged event handler and an override of OnAppearing, as follows:

```java
private Dictionary<int, double> _worksiteFrameSizeMap = new Dictionary<int, double>();

public void worksiteGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;

    if (grid != null)
    {
        var frame = grid.Parent as Frame;

        if (frame != null)
        {
            var worksite = grid.BindingContext as Worksite;

            if (worksite != null)
            {
                var frameHeight = 0.0;

                frameHeight += frame.Height;
                frameHeight += frame.Margin.Top;
                frameHeight += frame.Margin.Bottom;
                _worksiteFrameSizeMap[worksite.WorksiteId] = frameHeight;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var worksiteListViewHeight = 0.0;

    foreach (var item in _worksiteFrameSizeMap)
    {
        worksiteListViewHeight += item.Value;
    }
    worksiteList.HeightRequest = worksiteListViewHeight;
}
```

This is the only way I could get the list height so there is no blank space below the last list item (and I tried many others that didn't work). Unfortunately there is a slight blink as the page appears. I am inclined to think the ListView control has a bug because the ListView ought to do this automatically (does anyone ever want blank space below a list?) and there is no simple way to access the item sizes in a list.